# Can dermatophytes (toenail fungus) survive without oxygen?

Tags: mycology

I read that fungi in general can switch to alcohol fermentation in the absence of oxygen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_organism). How about dermatophytes ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatophyte aka toenail fungus) I read an interesting comment here http://gizmodo.com/cold-plasma-could-be-used-to-freeze-out-toenail-fungus-1734825446 by bra55orchid that

> "Topical infections like nail fungus and warts require access to the
>   open air. This is why they don't go systemic. Nail fungus progresses
>   as it degrades the nail to allow air to pass through it. Pine sap is
>   enough to kill them by sealing them off. Spores may survive in the
>   case of fungus, so you must keep them sealed off until the spores are
>   pushed out by nail growth."

Comment: PS I tried sealing off my nail, but it did not stop the fungus...

Comment: Try IPL (laser) treatment for toenail fungus, it's guaranteed to work. All other treatments never remove the entire fungae and they always come back. It will take 3-6 months for the healthy toenail to grow back nice and shiny, the fungae might be dead but the ugly nail growth will take time to be replaced naturally.

Comment: Tried laser (not sure if IPL) but it is very painful, as the laser goes deeper than the fungus, so it also hurts healtthy tissue. What worked for me is cutting out the entire affected nail as it no longer attaches to the nail bed.